# Weird error with binary tree and a printf

Tags: c, printf, binary-search-tree

This is the part of the code that creates a node, suppose c = "correctword". the first printf prints "TEST correctword". but the second printf prints "TEST TEST", why is this happening? from one to another I just used a strcpy, pNo->item.key should be "correctword", what am I doing wrong?:

```
TNo* TNo_Create (char* c){
    TNo* pNo = malloc(sizeof(TNo));
    printf("TEST %s", c);
    strcpy(pNo->item.key, c);
    printf("TEST %s", pNo->item.key);
    pNo->item.no = 1;
    pNo->pLeft = NULL;
    pNo->pRight = NULL;
    printf("TEST %s, %d\n", pNo->item.key, pNo->item.no);
    return pNo;
}
```

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct Item{
    char* key;
    int no;
} TItem;

typedef struct No{
    TItem item;
    struct No* pLeft;
    struct No* pRight;
} TNo;
```

Comment: Also, if I remove the two first printf, the program stops working with no reason (before it reaches the last printf)

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for `pNo->item.key`.

Comment: lol, it was this... C can be bizarre with people who have no idea what are doing hahaha thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, here's the code as it should be:

```
TNo* pNo = malloc(sizeof(TNo));
printf("TEST %s", c);
pNo->item.key = malloc(strlen(c)+1);
strcpy(pNo->item.key, c);
printf("TEST %s", pNo->item.key);
```